# Application only getting changes from config file after recompiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a .Net application to send emails using System.Net.Mail. The method in my service file is as follows:

```
    private void EmailRecords()
    {
        string toField = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toName"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toField))
        {
            List<ClientCarrierResponse> responseRecords = ClientCarrierDao.GetAllEmailRecords(Connection, File.RequestPkid, File.CarrierPkid);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromName"]);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toField));
            message.Subject = GetMessageSubject(File);
            message.Body = GetMessageBody(responseRecords);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;


            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Send(message);

        }
    }
```

The App.config file then has the appropriate parameters:

```
<configuration>
 <!-- Other config settings -->

<!-- Configuration for specifying SMTP host for sending e-mails-->
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="mail.exampleSMTP.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
 </system.net>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="toName" value="example@email.com" />
   <add key="fromName" value="source@email.com" />
 </appSettings>
```

I've noticed that if I change the network host address in the app config file to something incorrect that it doesn't fail unless I recompile the code. (the same goes with switching it back after, i.e. it doesn't successfully send the mails unless I recompile the code after fixing the address)

I've tried changing it via Visual studio and also changing the app.config and the appName.exe.config files manually.

What am I doing wrong that it isn't reading the parameters dynamically?

Comment: Strange...Simple restart of an app should re-read config.

Comment: Are you changing the correct config file? When you compile VS copies your config file from the development folder to the build (debug or release), folder.

Comment: I believe so but to be sure that's why I altered both the app.config and the appName.exe.config in the bin folder